# Capacitor.isNative changes value when reloading page in Webview or when restarting app

Tags: android, capacitor, single-spa, single-spa-angular

In the capacitor app we are developing for Android we load the entire app from a url using ***server.url***  in ***capacitor.config.json***.

Our app is a single-spa application which loads angular apps as multiple microfrontends. We build our app using the commands:

1. *npm run build* (this builds the root config for single-spa)
2. *npx cap sync android*
3. *npx cap open android*
4. then build APK using Android Studio

Then we try doing the following code in one of our angular components. It is done to conditionally implement some platform specific logic in component.

```js
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
console.log(Capacitor.isNative); 
//this logs "true" when loading the app after clearing app data or loading app for first time
//but logs "false" when reloading the webview using chrome debugger or when closing app and opening again(without clearing data)
```

In our case the **Capacitor.isNative** field changes from being **true** to **false** after reloading using chrome debugger or closing and opening app again. Is there something extra we have to do to make sure that Capacitor recognizes the App as a native app? Anybody has any idea as to why the Capacitor object changes after we reload the page?

We have tried using other Capacitor APIs for detecting platform like **Capacitor.getPlatform()** and **Capacitor.platform**. Both of these change from "android" to "web" after reopening app or reloading the page using chrome debugger.

We have also seen similar behavior when trying to load other Capacitor Plugins wherein the plugin object changes its structure(i.e. presumably the web implementation gets loaded instead of Android specific implementation) after the page is reloaded or app is restarted. Has anybody faced issues similar to this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved this?

Comment: @GeorgeB apparently it was an issue with the service worker that we were using. From my understanding it(service worker) was loading resources from the webview cache instead of from server we deployed when loading the app for the second time and that was throwing off the getPlatform/isNative APIs. Another senior engineer from my team fixed it and this was the brief context that I got from him, I couldn't verify the solution myself that's why I didn't update with an answer  so please take this with a grain of salt